# unable to run react native project in linux

Tags: android, ios, linux, react-native

If I create a new project, it works. But this project was built in Windows and when i run it in linux i get following errors.

```
error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transformFile')
    at Bundler.transformFile (/home/muaz/Desktop/stylon/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:48:30)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Object.transform (/home/muaz/Desktop/stylon/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:101:12)
    at async processModule (/home/muaz/Desktop/stylon/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:137:18)
    at async traverseDependenciesForSingleFile (/home/muaz/Desktop/stylon/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:131:3)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async initialTraverseDependencies (/home/muaz/Desktop/stylon/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:114:3)
    at async DeltaCalculator._getChangedDependencies (/home/muaz/Desktop/stylon/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/DeltaCalculator.js:164:25)
    at async DeltaCalculator.getDelta (/home/muaz/Desktop/stylon/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/DeltaCalculator.js:94:16)
    at async DeltaBundler.buildGraph (/home/muaz/Desktop/stylon/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler.js:50:5)
```

[image: Err]

Answer (score 0):

This issue was caused by Node version. At time of project creation, Node version was 16. After upgrading to latest this issue occurred. On downgrading to Nodejs 16, it works